# sentTextMessage() is not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to send sms to another number like this:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
String sent = "android.telephony.SmsManager.STATUS_ON_ICC_SENT";
        PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                sent), 0);
sms.sendTextMessage("+5581(rest of the number)", null, msg, piSent, null);
```

Apparently, it works, but i've sent a message hours ago and still no messages. Here's my manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

I've tried with just the number, without the country code, with the country code, with the '+' sign...nothing worked.

I've read that it could fail "silently" if not called within an activity. I even created another activity just to send the sms on onCreate method, but with no success. Is there something i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

what you have done is absolutely right, just need to do one modification, remove "pisent" from sent message and insert null. The below code is working for me:

```
SmsManager mSmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
mSmsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNumber", null, "Message", null,
                    null);
```

Comment: Didn't work either. My device is a Samsung galaxy s4 with Android 4.4.2. I've read that this method doesn't work on some devices...